# Why server-less CosmosDB is too much slow when we update the indices?

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have migrated all my databases to CosmosDB with Mongo API by removing indices. After the migration, I started creating indices manually on CosmosDB. I have a collection called to order. It has 7 Million documents each document is nearly 1 KB in size. But as I update the index it is taking a lot of time. I am checking the index update status. It is been 30 minutes still the update is only 40 % complete. is this index update is a lot of RU consuming operation.? I know we have a limitation of 5000 RU/s per container. So is this slowness is because of that. If someone knows the answer to this please help me. And also, will the Azure cost me for the RU's that I consume during an index update. I have read somewhere that it won't.

Comment: Not sure anyone can answer your question regarding how long your indexing should take, or how to define "slowness."

Comment: @DavidMakogon In serverless cosmos DB we have a limitation of 5000 RU. The usual way of doing an index update when the CosmosDB is a provisioned one is like, we will scale up the RU during the index update and will scale down to the old value afterwards. But how that. Just wanted to confirm that the RU limitation is the cause of this much time for the index update and if there is a better solution I am seeking that as well.